# From Servlet to JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

When trying to pass a table built with HTML in my servlet like that:

```
response.setContentType("text/html" );  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
out.println("<html>" );  
out.println("<head>" );  
out.println("<title>Imput OPC</title>" );
out.println("</head>" );  
out.println("<body>" ); 
...
```

and then

```
response.sendRedirect("/xxx.jsp" );
```

But I did not found any table in the JSP.
A friend told me to use a Bean but how can i catch values from the form ( because I have a treatement with the form before constructing table)in a bean. I must use a servlet for that. So what I want is exactly to construct in the response a table then send it to jsp knowing that: `.sendRedirect` and

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/xxx.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

gives nothing at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *redirect* let the client fire a **new** request. It trashes the current request and response you're working on. You get a fresh new request and response on the specified URL. You don't want to send a redirect whenever you want to pass request scoped information from servlet to JSP. Use a *forward* instead.

Printing HTML in a servlet is a big no-no. You should also not write something to the response body whenever you want to forward the request to a JSP later. You would face an `IllegalStateException` in the server logs (and indeed a blank page in the webbrowser). Printing HTML is a task which is to be done by JSP, not by servlet.

In a servlet you just need to do the business stuff. E.g. collecting information which is to be displayed in a table. First create a Javabean class which represents each item (row) of the table. Then create a DAO class which returns a list of those items from the datastore (a database?). Then in the servlet, just put the list of items in the request scope using [`HttpServletRequest#setAttribute()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), forward the request to a JSP file using [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) and iterate over the list of items using [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`c:forEach`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) tag (to install JSTL, just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib`).

Basic kickoff example:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Item> items = itemDAO.list();
    request.setAttribute("items", items); // It's now available as ${items} in EL.
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

where `/WEB-INF/result.jsp` look like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

...

<table>
    <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
        <tr>
            <td>${item.someProperty}</td>
            <td>${item.anotherProperty}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

For more hints and examples you may find [those tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) useful. To go some steps further, you can also use a MVC framework so that you basically end up with only a Javabean class and a JSP file (i.e. the role of the servlet have been taken over by the MVC framework), for example [JSF](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/).

Comment: Think you  for the answer I will be more clear.
What I want to realize is th following:
In a JSP x I have a 3 dropdownlist and a button called edit when user click this button a table dynamically should be displayed now this table is modified correponding the values in those 3 ddl.
So it can be 3 cols or 4 cols or even 6 cols it depends on the selected values.
So what I tried is to use the servlet to getParameter doing the if clause construct the html and then forward the response.Have you any the suggestion of the structure that I can use.

Comment: I still confused untill now.Thinks a lot for the usefull help that you give to me.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have a completely new and independent question, press `Ask Question` button at the right top. Don't forget to mark answers of previous questions accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but have you tried:

`request.getRequestDispatcher("/xxx.jsp").forward(request, response);`

The `response.sendRedirect("/xxx.jsp" )` is just what it is, it tells the browser to go look somewhere else (http 301 with a location header of "../xxx.jsp"). No information is passed along in this redirect. That's what RequestDispatcher is for.